# The declaration was marked as deprecated here

Tags: angular, deprecated

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.olxSell.getAllProperties().subscribe(
      
      data=>{
        this.Properties=data;
        console.log(data);
      }, error=> {
        console.log('httperror:');
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
```

Comment: What declaration ? Provide enough context. Please checkout how to make a SOF posts

Answer (score -1):

With `rxjs` v7, the new way to subscribe goes as follows:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.olxSell.getAllProperties().subscribe({
    next: data => {
      this.Properties=data;
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: error => {
      console.log('httperror:');
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
}
```

Check out the docs: https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable